# SQL Server 2008 R2 to MySQL Migration

Tags: mysql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, mysql-workbench

Is there a GUI tool out there that will allow me to migrate entire SQL Server 2008 R2 databases to MySQL?  I have MySQL Workbench installed, but it looks like there isn't a feature in it like SSIS to copy and paste entire databases from SQL Server.  I downloaded the MySQL Migration Toolkit, but it is no longer supported and I get a Java error when running it.

Comment: I found this : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9OHXCYRYjRs (14 sept.2013) but I haven't tested yet. I hope it may help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The new version of MySQL Workbench incorporated the old Migration Toolkit.  You can now do direct imports / exports between different databases inside of MySQL Workbench.

To get to the Migration Wizard, click on 'Database' on the tab menu.  Then select 'Migrate'

Answer (score 1):

What version of the Workbench brings back the Migration Toolkit? I don't see it in 5.2.45 CE so maybe this is a full version feature?

Comment: This "answer" should probably be a comment, since it doesn't answer the question.

Comment: I have Workbench 5.2 CE.  On the tab bar, click on 'Database' → 'Migrate'

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try [Navicat Premium](http://www.navicat.com)

Comment: Thanks, but I'd like to stick to freeware

Comment: You can get free trial.  If this is a one time thing, then you might not need it again.  Then again if this is something you do all the time, a paid tool (if it is the best solution for you) can make a lot of sense.